# How can I communicate via phone hotspot local network?

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, hotspot, local-network

I'm working on a RPi project and wanna control RPi wirelessly.
So I want to use phone hotspot to connect pc(or laptop) with raspberry pi.
I wrote the simple server, client code and tested it, but I can't send data from pc to rpi neither by TCP, UDP.

To be simple, what I want is
(PC---phone(hotspot)---RPi)     communication,
using IP such as 192.168.12.345.

The problem is, when I try same code with
(PC---WIFI router---RPi)  connection,
it works well. Both TCP and UDP.

I wonder is there any job to do more with hotspot network?

Answer (score 0):

Meh...
I was dumb.
I connected pc with tethering(which is 192.168.42.xxx)
and connected rpi with hotspot(192.168.43.xxx)
so it was in different subnet.
Problem was solved just by changing tethering to both hotspot.
It seems vpn or phone rooting are needed to sync the ip for two different connection method